# update data in 2 table by avlue frome select statement in oracle

Tags: oracle

Hi I want to change a value to some number by in table1 by inter (*some existed value*) then i want to update another value in table2 by the out bout from a select statement using same (*some existed value*). I try something like this:

```
update  decrees set laststatusid = 4 
where decreeid = ALL (Num1,Num2,....Num100);

UPDATE REQUESTS SET LASTSTATUSID = 22
   WHERE REQUESTID = ALL ((
                SELECT REQUESTID 
                FROM DECREES
                WHERE DECREEID = ALL(Num1,Num2,....Num100));
```

it works to one number but when i insert multi number it didn't work
your fast response will be appreciated
thanks.

Comment: Mysql or Oracle?

Comment: oracle and i use toad for oracle

Comment: Then remove the `MySQL` tag.  Why is it there to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is using `= ALL` when you should be using `IN`.

Unless I am not understanding your problem, you are trying to update many rows at once but your decreeID is a *single* value, it will never be equal to a *whole set* of values, which is what you are trying to achieve with `= ALL`.

On the other hand, it explains why it would work with a single value.

Example :

```
UPDATE decrees
SET laststatusid = 4
WHERE decreeid IN(Num1, Num2, .... Num100);

UPDATE REQUESTS
SET LASTSTATUSID = 22
WHERE REQUESTID IN (SELECT REQUESTID
                    FROM DECREES
                    WHERE DECREEID IN(Num1, Num2, .... Num100));
```

Comment: it work for the 2nd  statement but not for the 1st statement

Comment: @khaledahmed I can't see what could go wrong with the first statement, it is actually very straightforward. Can you explain what is not working? Actual vs expected result? Error message?

Comment: the 1st statement didn't show any wrong or  error  massage but the  table had no change   i try to use  =ANY and it is work but when i run each statement one by the time (not together)

Comment: @khaledahmed and if you try to run `SELECT * FROM decrees WHERE decreeid IN(Num1, Num2, .... Num100);` does it return something? That's a way to verify if the `WHERE` clause is "working".

Comment: yes this select   SELECT * FROM decrees WHERE decreeid IN(Num1, Num2, .... Num100);  statement is work successfully

Comment: i run the 1st statement in  sqlplus  reternet this                                                      
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Tue Oct 24 21:02:34 2017
Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
Input truncated to 7499 characters
SP2-0027: Input is too long (> 2499 characters) - line ignored
SP2-0042: unknown command ")" - rest of line ignored.
Input truncated to 7499 characters
SP2-0027: Input is too long (> 2499 characters) - line ignored
SP2-0042: unknown command "))" - rest of line ignored.
Commit complete.